# Android scale canvas does not working

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

i'm trying to make a photo crop app and i want to load a large size image and scale it to to 480 Width and 800 Height (keep aspect ratio) but the problem is if i scale bitmap it shrinks image and when i save it the result get low quality so i decided to scale its canvas to keep bitmap original size.
i need to keep original size but scale the image to fit in screen?

here is my code:

```
public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
myCanvas = new Canvas(finalBitmap);
myCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
myCanvas.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
isLoaded = true;
}
```

draw method:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (isLoaded)
        canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}
```

i changed scalefactor with 0.9f ,480,... but non of them had effect on bitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this

```
canvas.save();
canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
canvas.restore();
```

Another option is to use the drawBitmap that does the scaling for you with the following call `canvas.drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)`

Comment: Thank you scale on ondraw canvas perfectly worked it only had issue on mycanvas

Comment: i have another problem now . i can't put the image in the center of the screen------------ canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(x, x);
            float y = finalBitmap.getHeight() * 480f / finalBitmap.getWidth();
            canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, 0, ((yscaleFactor * 800f/2) - y/2 ), null);
            canvas.restore();

Comment: Do not use the scale factor when calculating the center, as the canvas does that when it scales each call.

Comment: after too much try finally i used your second solution and everything went well . thanks again ;)